# Which is correct title for my blog: "Professor Message" or "Professor's Message"?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I have asked a question related to this. But now, I need final clarification to remove the confusion to name my site's title.

Comment: Though there is nothing ungrammatical about using a noun as a modifier, here it would sound outlandish.

Answer (score 4):

*Professor Message* sounds like the blog of a professor named "Message," so unless that's what you want, I would strongly recommend the second option.

Comment: OK then, what about "Literati Book" or "Literati's Book"?